# How to secure a web API from being accessed from unauthorized SPAs

Tags: javascript, web-services, security, oauth-2.0

I am building a B2B service whose API can be accessed by third-parties on a subscription basis. Basically, we provide a customizable widget that our customers can embed on their website to make it available to their customers (e.g. a button that opens a modal). While it is clear how to make this work in a traditional web app, I am not sure how to guarantee this in a single-page app. Is it at all possible to make this work without a redirect URI as used in OAuth? That is, the modal triggers AJAX requests to our API and we want to make sure it comes from a script from an authorized origin *without* redirects. We could of course simply check Origin header, but what is there to prevent someone from constructing a request with such a header on their backend manually, even though they couldn't do it in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem

> While it is clear how to make this work in a traditional web app, I am not sure how to guarantee this in a single-page app.

From a web app you only need to see the html source code to be able to find the API keys or other secrets. Even if you use a traditional web server, cookies can also be obtained to automate attacks against it.

While [this series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of articles about Mobile API Security Techniques are in the context of mobile devices, some of the techniques used are also valid in other type of APIs, like APIs for Web/SPAs apps, and you can see how API keys, OUATH tokens and HMAC secrets can be used  to protect an API and bypassed.

## Possible Solution

You can try to make it hard to find the API key with a [Javascript Obfuscator](https://obfuscator.io/), but bear in mind that this only delays an attacker in succeeding.

#### So, how can I block an attacker?

Well the cruel truth is... You can't!!!

But you can try, by using [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) from Google, that works in the background, therefore doesn't require user interaction. The drawback here is that all your B2B clients would need to implemente it across all pages of their websites, thus may not be the way to go for your use case...

[reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.

If your B2B solution really needs to protect it at all costs then you need to employ Web Application Firewalls(WAF) and User Behavior Analytics solutions, also know as UBA, that use Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning to prevent abuse, but once more they cannot guarantee 100% blocking and both have false positives.

[WAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

## Conclusion

In the end of the day you can only protect your B2B back-end in a best effort basis, that must be proportional to the value it holds for the business.

A 100% solution doesn't exist for the web, due to the way it was designed to work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter where the request comes from or who is making the request? If the latter needs confirmation then you could require an authorization token along with the request. Normally, you would do this in such a way that you could decode the token and confirm a match with an authorized party.

Comment: Sorry, I think I forgot to mention the issue here is with single-page apps. How can we issue a client secret used to obtain the authorization token to each customer if it is not able to store it confidentially?

Comment: Yes, you would need to store the private key securely.

Comment: Okay, but what if our customers cannot store it in such a manner?

Comment: It is up to them to safeguard their credentials. Anything sent over the wire should be assumed to be in plain text. I would bet if there is enough concern about security then a way could be found to safely encrypt without revealing sensitive information. It is done all the time.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want system security, you can use Oauth2.0 grant type = client credentials. This will make sure you api's is being used by only authorized clients.

Working of it is very simple, client hit an Oauth2.0 server with client_id and client_pass and Oauth server returns you a token, the same token client will pass to the server and when you verify that token by hitting the Oauth server with server_id,server_pass+token to Oauth server it returns validation with client id and based on that you can expose your services.
You do not need to worry about redirection as client credentials does not require that.

Comment: I know about OAuth grant types. The type of client I am concerned with is an _SPA_. It cannot store a client secret.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using OAuth2 Auth Code with PKCE. It's designed to allow securely calling APIs from SPAs (and native apps). Basically, it relies on the fact that the SPA calling your API has some well known URL, and this is what disallows its usage outside of your SPA.